# Get Xbox One surround sound to speakers through PC?

Tags: audio

My 5.1 speakers have 3, 3.5mm inputs for rear/center/front, and the Xbox One outputs either optical DTS/AC3 or HDMI uncompressed surround. I want to get surround sound from the Xbox One to the PC so I can output to the speakers. I can't think of a convenient way to do this, even without the PC.

My monitor only has a single 3.5mm output so HDMI audio isn't an option there, and my computer doesn't have an optical input. I have tried to use a USB sound card, but it can't decode DTS/AC3. I was thinking if I could do it through software since but after googling around I can't find a way to even decode any recording device with anything.

What would be a convenient way to get surround from Xbox (optical/hdmi) to a PC/3.5mm speaker? And if there's a way to, can I decode DTS/AC3 using software?

Comment: With your current setup it isn't possible.  Xbox One will only do Surround Sound through the optical connection it has.

Comment: decoding DTS/AC3 through software? or am i thinking of something that isnt possible. also hdmi is an option, and i'm not limiting the question to my setup, i can get additional components but i dont want $100+ of components just to get this to work